# Impossible to call wordpress function inside an include?

Tags: functions, include

In my Plugin, I have an object 'Settings' (to display stuff in Wordpress settings).

**Settings.php**

```
<?php

namespace FooNamespace\Admin\Settings;

class Settings {

    public $menu_slug;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->menu_slug = 'settings-'.PLUGIN_DOMAIN ;

        // Initialize the component
        $this->init();

    }

    protected function init(){

        // output method
        add_action( '_output_content_submenu_page_' . $this->menu_slug, array( $this, 'html_page_template' ) );
    }

    public function html_page_template(){

        include_once 'views/view-settings.php';

    }


 }
```

In 'view-settings.php', I can normally use all basic wordpress functions.

**view-settings.php**

```
<div class="wrap">

    <h1 class="wp-heading-inline">
        <?php _e('Settings for '.PLUGIN_TITLE, PLUGIN_DOMAIN); ?>
    </h1>
    <hr wp-header-end />

    <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
        ...
    </h2>

    <?php foreach ($tabs as $tab ){ ?>
            <?php include_once $tab["path"]; ?>
    <?php } ?>

</div>
```

But in my included file ( `include_once $tab["path"];` ), I cannot use the wordpress function like `__()` or `_e()`.

**Included file**

```
<form id="form-settings-recaptach" method="post">
    <table class="widefat fixed">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label class="label"><?php _e( "Foo", PLUGIN_DOMAIN ); ?></label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

So I get this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function _e()

***Notice** : if I include the child php file directly inside Settings.php, the functions are called. So It's a real problem of include inside an iclude and levels for Wordpress*

Why ? How can I debug this ?

Comment: The `_e('Settings for '.PLUGIN_TITLE, PLUGIN_DOMAIN);` working in the `view-settings.php`? another way, use `require_once` for include your file.

Comment: where is called the action `_output_content_submenu_page_...` ?

Comment: Yes, the \_e('Settings for '.PLUGIN_TITLE, PLUGIN_DOMAIN) works. Ok, I will try with require_once. For the action '\_output_content_submenu_page_', it's called in an other object which make the submenu page.

Comment: Same problem with require_once.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem and I have the solution :
To include the child file, as I'm working on localhost I changed the path :

**My error :**

```
 plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'my-child-template.php' //<-- \path\to\file/my-child-template.php

 //Changed by
 plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'my-child-template.php' //<-- http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/path/to/file/my-child-template.php
```

With the second path, it worked on localhost, it managed to include the template but impossible to call worpdress functions.

So, I had to find a solution to include the path file instead of the url but with a localhost compatibility.

**The solution is :**

```
public function html_page_template(){
    ob_start();
    $ipAddress = gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
    if( $ipAddress === "127.0.0.1"){
        $base_path =  dirname( __FILE__ )."\\templates\\";
    }else{
        $base_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."templates/";
    }
    $a_settings_tab = array( 
        0 => array(
            "key" => "foo",
            "path" =>  $base_path ."foo.php"
        ), 
        1 => array(
            "key" => "bar",
            "path" =>  $base_path ."bar.php"
        )
    );

    include_once 'views/view-settings.php';
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    echo $html;
}
```

Comment: sorry, but this doesn't make much sense, And if you are actually including a url, it is totally wrong.

Comment: Yes, that was wrong to include an url, I had to include the path file. It's exactly I'm explaining in this solution.

Comment: ok, so the problem was with your question, still trying to detect on which server the code run is wrong by itself

Comment: How is someone supposed to know where the error was with a question like that?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem in past

try using `include` with `locate_template`:
I don't exactly remember the reason but this code still works:

Example:
`include(locate_template(YOUR_TEMPLATE_PATH));`

[Here's](http://jeroensormani.com/how-to-add-template-files-in-your-plugin/) a complete demonstration too, using the same idea, if you need more help.

**For Admin Panel**

`include` simply works in admin panel.

You might want to modify your code like:

```
public function init(){
    add_menu_page( 'Your Plugin Name' , 'Your Plugin Settings' , 'manage_options' , 'your_plugin_settings' ,  array( $this, 'settings_page' ) );
}
public function html_page_template(){
    ob_start();
    include('views/view-settings.php');
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    echo $html;
}
```

If the `init` function is calling your custom hook, then please don't modify it and make sure that code is working properly. Your `html_page_template` function should now output the form.

Comment: locate_template => _"Retrieve the name of the highest priority template file that exists."_. I am in **admin > Settings > My PLugin Name**, I do not use any template like 'page.php' at this location. So unfortunately, that does not work. I have any response from this function :/

Comment: Thank you for your answer about Admin panel, but it's already like this ^^

Comment: I see that you're not using 'echo' to print the markup. Would you please post the updated code and the function hook `'_output_content_submenu_page_' . $this->menu_slug`. If still you think it's not helping then please check [this template](https://github.com/hlashbrooke/WordPress-Plugin-Template).

Though I've tested my code and it works. There must be some error in other files which you haven't posted.